# Google cloud kubernetes load balancer, health check on the backend isn't working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

I am duplicating a Kubernetes cluster containing [divolte](https://divolte.io/) from one GCP (Google Cloud Platform) project to another. I have the exact same configurations in the already running project as the target project. In my new project I don't get load balancer running with the right health check and when I try to connect to te static IP form the load balancer I get a 502 server error.

I've followed the same steps as in the original project:

1. Creating a cluster on GCP
2. Authorize local kubectl to the cluster on GCP
3. Add TLS secret to kubernetes cluster on GCP
4. Create static global IP
5. build the docker file with divolte
6. push the docker file to eu.gcr.io/project-name
7. apply the deployment, ingress and service file

Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: divolte
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: divolte
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: divolte
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: divolte
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "eu.gcr.io/project-name/divolte-collector:latest"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8290
        env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.awt.headless=true"
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 3072Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 2048Mi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /divolte.js
            port: 8290
          initialDelaySeconds: 22
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: 8290
          initialDelaySeconds: 22
          periodSeconds: 1
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: divolte
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8290
    nodePort: 30964
  selector:
    app: divolte
  type: NodePort
```

Ingress file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: divolte
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ip-name-here
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ssl-cert-name-here
  backend:
    serviceName: divolte
    servicePort: 80
```

I expected that the load balancer would pick up the configuration file as in my previous GCP project and would reroute the traffic to the cluster correctly, but I cannot get my GCP load balancer with the health check to work. Any ideas what to do next?

Comment: Is every resources in your cluster up and running? can you access the app using port-forwarding?

Comment: What error message are you seeing in the ingress? Sometimes a yellow icon appears while the HTTPS load balancer and its backends are set.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the problem.

Thanks for the suggestions, I was looking to a sympton in the load balancer, but it was the wrong direction.

The kubernetes pods were stuck in a "crashloopbackoff" because I forgot to create a Google Storage bucket, it wasn't in my documentation to setup the environment so I overlooked it. I found it with the "kubectl logs" command. The app is up and running now.